# Mostrar la cantidad de relaciones en el menú de opciones

Tags: python, django, django-forms

quiero implementar un formulario que me muestre el numero de personas que pertenecen a una actividad en cada uno de los items dentro del `ModelChoicesField`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo Profesion

```
class Profesion(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 60, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('nombre'))
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('descripcion'))
```

Modelo Persona

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('nombre'))
    profesion = models.ManyToManyField(Profesion, blank=True, verbose_name=_('profesiones'))
```

Formulario

```
class PersonaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    label_suffix = ':'

    class Meta:
        model = Persona

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PersonaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'

        self.fields['profesion'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'select2'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'profesion'
            ),
        }
```

View

```
class PersonaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Persona
    template_name = 'form.html'
    form_class = PersonaForm
    page_title = 'Crear Persona'
```

HTML

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
               <div class="widget-body">
                    <form method="post" id="form_persona">
                        {% crispy form %}
                    </form>
               </div>
```

Comment: Carga los datos desde la view, que será un `count()` sobre un `queryset` por cada tipo de actividad, encapsula en variables esos datos, pásalos al template y desde ahí, o bien los muestras de forma "fija", o bien los muestras en un desplegable.

Comment: No sé qué opciones tienes con la librería que usas, y hay forma de hacerlo manual sin la librería, con la librería no sé, supongo que será igual. En todo caso, para obtener la cantidad de personas por profesión bastaría con esto: `Profesion.objects.all().prefetch_related('persona_set')` ese sería el query y cuando recorres a cada uno sería algo como: `[p.persona_set.count() for p in Profesion.objects.all().prefetch_related('persona_set')]`. Ponerlo en el option del select, es cuestion de modificar como creas y renderizas el formulario

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera

Form

```
class ProfesionModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
        def label_from_instance(self, obj):
             return "%s (%s)" % (obj.nombre, Persona.objects.filter(profesion=obj).count())

class PersonaForm(forms.ModelForm):
        profesion= ProfesionModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Profesion.objects.all(), required=False, label="Profesiones")
```